# Data entry using com.google.gson

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to create a Gson object which will contain differents categories and entries
Here is the sample i'm trying  to do:

```
        JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
    JsonArray ja = new  JsonArray();
    JsonObject mainObj = new JsonObject();


jo.addProperty("firstName", "John");
jo.addProperty("lastName", "Doe");

 ja.add(jo);

 mainObj.add("employees", ja);

jo = new JsonObject();
ja = new JsonArray();


jo.addProperty("firstName", "jean");
jo.addProperty("lastName", "dorian");

ja.add(jo);

mainObj.add("employees", ja);

jo = new JsonObject();
ja = new JsonArray();

jo.addProperty("firstName", "toto");
jo.addProperty("lastName", "tata");

ja.add(jo);

mainObj.add("manager", ja);
```

The problem is has you can see I have to create every time a new JSonObject and Array which is I believe not the best practice and also the old value in "employees" is replacing by the second.
Someone can help me on this please?

Br,

Jérémie

Answer (score 0):

> I have to create every time a new JSonObject and Array which is I
> believe not the best practice

I think it's perfectly fine to do it like this.

> and also the old value in "employees" is replacing by the second

The problem is that you want to add a mapping `"employees" -> JsonArray` two times in your `JsonObject`. While online JSON parsers such as JSONLint don't say anything about that, it's actually not recommended to have two identical keys in a `JsonObject`.

This is explained in the [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159), chapter 4:

> An object whose names are all unique is interoperable in the sense
> that all software implementations receiving that object will agree on
> the name-value mappings.  When the names within an object are not
> unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is
> unpredictable.  Many implementations report the last name/value pair
> only.  Other implementations report an error or fail to parse the
> object, and some implementations report all of the name/value pairs,
> including duplicates.

Under the hood, the `JsonObject` structure is implemented with a `LinkedTreeMap` to save the mappings. When you add a new mapping, the `put` method is called, which will erase the previous mapped value, if any.

```
90  @Override public V put(K key, V value) {
91    if (key == null) {
92      throw new NullPointerException("key == null");
93    }
94    Node<K, V> created = find(key, true);
95    V result = created.value;
96    created.value = value;
97    return result;
98  }
```

If you want to add another `Employee` to the array, you shouldn't add it directly to the `JsonObject` and create a new `JsonArray`.

```
JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
JsonArray ja = new  JsonArray();
JsonObject mainObj = new JsonObject();


jo.addProperty("firstName", "John");
jo.addProperty("lastName", "Doe");

ja.add(jo);

//remove this line
mainObj.add("employees", ja);

jo = new JsonObject();

//and remove this line
ja = new JsonArray();


jo.addProperty("firstName", "jean");
jo.addProperty("lastName", "dorian");

ja.add(jo);

mainObj.add("employees", ja);

jo = new JsonObject();
ja = new JsonArray();

jo.addProperty("firstName", "toto");
jo.addProperty("lastName", "tata");

ja.add(jo);

mainObj.add("manager", ja);
```

which will result in:

```
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "jean",
      "lastName": "dorian"
    }
  ],
  "manager": [
    {
      "firstName": "toto",
      "lastName": "tata"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Alexis C. thanks for your feedback I finally use org.json librairy which have accumalate option and allow you to add values under a same key it was not really what I was thinking to do but it s ok I can use it.

Comment: @sadill Ok, but be aware that you are building data that are broken. I.e, if you plan to transfer them between various JSON parsers, you might loss informations or make the program crash.